# calling specific variable from one method to the main class

Tags: java, variables, methods

How to call a variable from a method by a class?

Code sample;

```
public class House{
public static void main(String args[]){

 system.out.println(Name);



}

public void Types() {

 String Name = House
 int number = 1;

 String Name = Flat
 int number = 2;
}

}
```

I want to call the variable Name from my Types method to the main class. 
---- The code above is completely random and does not have any main purpose, I just want to know how to call a single variable from a method by a class. ----

Comment: You don't. You either return it, or create an instance and use a property getter, e.g., `getName()` that returns an *instance* variable, not a variable local to a method.

Comment: Just create an instance of that class and access it

Comment: @NeerajKrishna Not from main, you can't, not without exposing it somehow as my comment.

Comment: See: http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jrs/4/lec/08

Comment: @  Neeraj Krishna and  Dave Newton could you please show me an example?

Comment: Keep in mind your values for `Name` (twice) are both invalid.  I think you meant to have those "values" in strings: `String name = "House"` and `String name2 = "Flat"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name here is a local type, it cant be referenced in main method.

Try making a class member example

```
package com.test;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        B b = new B();
        System.out.println(b.name);
    }
}

class B
{
    String name="test";
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The user seems pretty new to Java.  Perhaps you could initialize the value of `name` such that this won't give a null pointer error.

Comment: Changed as suggested.

Comment: its working now, there was a different code before when I was testing it ago.